# Partitioning bipartite graphs into bicliques

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, bipartite, subgraph, clique-problem

Is there an efficient (say in O(|V|^2)) and preferably not overly complicated algorithm for dividing a bipartite graph into the smallest possible number of bicliques? The vertices can repeat, so that all of the edges are contained.

I tried searching for it but couldn't understand some papers on this topic.

I'll be grateful for any help :)

In the mathematical fields of graph theory and combinatorial optimization, the **bipartite dimension** or **biclique cover number** of a graph G = (V, E) is the minimum number of bicliques (that is complete bipartite subgraphs), needed to cover all edges in E. A collection of bicliques covering all edges in G is called a **biclique edge cover**, or sometimes **biclique cover**. The bipartite dimension of G is often denoted by the symbol d(G).

I'd like help efficiently finding a biclique cover that realizes d(G) for an input bipartite graph G.

Comment: Can you share your network data?  That is a first step to getting the best answer here.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What is an "induced biclique"?  There is a straightforward algorithm for finding the maximal cliques in a graph.  I cannot tell from your question if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Best way forward would be to post a small example graph and show what you want to get as output.

Comment: Given that the problem of determining whether a bipartite graph contains a biclique of size k  is NP-complete, I'd say the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: @Ben so the input would be two sets of vertices size n and some edges connecting vertices from different sets. Output: minimal number of sets of vertices that partition given graph into biclicques (with each vertice in these sets listed)

Comment: @ravenspoint hmm, perhaps this algorithm could be used iteratively to find smaller and smaller biclicques. I guess it could work, even if the graph is not that dense so that there are many iterations - then each iteration wouldn't take much time

Comment: @ravenspoint I've added input and output in the comment above. I guess a simple example could be: we have a bipartite graph which is a union of some biclicques and I want the algorithm to list all the biclicques

Comment: @beaker that's what I feared, but perhaps finding maximum biclicques would suffice

Comment: sorry for the late reply, haven't noticed the notifications from you all. Thank you for the help up to this point though

Comment: @ravenspoint well I guess the word induced is redundant here, as every biclicque must be an induced subgraph here, but I hope you get the idea

Comment: I guess an important note is: the input graph is undirected and unweighted

Comment: @de_michael Do you need the smallest possible number of bicliques, or would a heuristic that gives a near-optimal solution be useful?

Comment: @Dave depends on what does  near-optimal mean. Do you have some specific algorithm in mind?

Comment: " the word induced is redundant here"  So why is it still in your question?  Please edit your question so it makes sense.

Comment: @de_michael Iterated Greedy is a fast and simple heuristic for finding clique covers that could be modified this problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_dimension

Comment: Is there anything you know about the input graph that you haven't mentioned? E.g., number of vertices, number of edges, presence of 4-cycles, division of vertices between the two halves, anything else?

Comment: @ravenspoint alright, I will edit, although it obviously still makes sense from the definition of an induced subgraph (you can find it online if you're not familiar)

Comment: @Dave it is an n, n bipartite graph, no info on number of edges, hence also no info on the number of 4-cycles (which can be present)

Comment: @Dave I've tried searching for the greedy heuristic, but all the content seems to be behind a paywall. Could you please link a free resource describing it or describe it here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255897/discussion-between-de-michael-and-dave).